# StyledEditorKit - Document - NotSerializableException

Tags: java, swing

I was evaluating the usability of StyledEditorKit used as the editor kit in the JTextPane(textpane). Once the user types any content into the editor and closes the editor, the program gets the Document(textpane.getDocument()) and try to serialize the object Document(

```
out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("f://test1234.ser"));
out.writeObject(doc);)
```

).

But in this moment a NotSerializableException is raised. However if the user doesn't type any text (the Document object wasn't changed by the editor) the app is able to serialize the Document object without problem. This behavior happens using Java 5 and 6, but not using 1.4.

Any ideas?

thanks. Felipo.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have to use one of the kit's write() method passing Writer or OutputStream. When you need to restore document you create an empty one and use read() method passing InputStream or Writer.
E.g. HTMLEditorKit produces html representation of content. RTFEditorKit produces rtf accordingly.
You can write your own Writer/Reader see for example
http://java-sl.com/editor_kit_tutorial_reader_writer.html